# Implementing RSA algorithm in iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, security, rsa, iphone-security

I have a scenario where I need to implement a digital signature scenario in iPhone and web. Simply I will first generate the RSA signature in iPhone end and share the public key with the server. Also server public key will be there using the x509 certificate generated from server. I can copy that over to the iPhone folder structure. The idea of this is to use this as digital signature where server will send a message by encrypting by the servers private key and again by iPhone public key. From iPhone end it can decrypt using iPphone private key and verity that again by decrypting using server public key.

I went through the sample code provided by Apple but they are not easy to understand. And it didn't cover my requirements as well. Here are my questions.

1) Can my objective achieved?

2) Will iPhone and my server back end (Java) work together cos many forums said that it had issues cos it has DER encoding.

3) Many samples focus on installing the own certificate in iPhone key chain. Can I install the server x509 as well?

4) Any link or material which will focus on my requirement or any guidance is appreciated.